# Using 1 sitemap but dynamically change the target location of each link

Tags: asp.net, sitemap

I have a sitemap file in my project.  None of the links on this file are contained on our server.  They all are located on another project.  We need this sitemap to mimic the navigation of the original site.

Right now the url is setup like this:

```
url-"~/folder a/file.aspx"
```

What I would like to do is dynamically change the server location of these links.  Is there a way to do that?

Basically I don't want to have to hard code the dev.server or the prod.server in the sitemap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is probably to create a custom [XmlSiteMapProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.xmlsitemapprovider.aspx) with a "base URL" property that your URLs will be appended to. You can then change your base URL to the appropriate site (dev/prodction).